# How can I see if a file on a remote webserver has been updated?

Tags: c#

A company publishes a file and updates it periodically.

Eg. `http://somecompany.com/blah/file.zip`

I'd like to poll once a day to see if it has been updated.

I'm guessing I can view the http headers to get the file size, or possibly a date/checksum that would indicate it had changed.

I'm wondering if there's an elegant solution to doing this in C# other than creating a direct TCP connection and sending some commands.

Any ideas?

Comment: The HTTP response header should have a field named `Last-Modified` which contains a GMT date and time value.

Comment: Creating a TCP Connection and sending some commands is "the" solution.

Comment: Thanks, wasn't sure if there was a C# class already like the ones for retrieving files, that could grab the info without actually performing the download.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As the file is on a remote web server you can use the `Last-Modified` header field to identify if there are any changes to the file.

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://somecompany.com/blah/file.zip");
request.Method = "HEAD"; // Important - Not interested in file contents

HttpWebResponse resp = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
Console.WriteLine(resp.LastModified);
```

Ensure you are using `HEAD` as the request method; As `GET` would download the file.

Comment: Excellent, thanks. That is considerably simpler than I expected.

Answer (score 0):

In a PCL you don't have access to the same objects are in the full .Net. So here is a more flexible bit of code:

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://somecompany.com/blah/file.zip");
request.Method = "HEAD"; // Important - Not interested in file contents
string lastModified = null;
ManualResetEvent mre = new ManualResetEvent(false);
var req = request.BeginGetResponse((result) =>
{
    var resp = (result.AsyncState as HttpWebRequest).EndGetResponse(result) as HttpWebResponse;
    lastModified = resp.Headers["Last-Modified"];
    mre.Set();
}, request);
mre.WaitOne();
```